# history.back(-1) not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

The scenario is, I have this old application in html and javascript. The first page/form has a dropdown list, a search text field, a find button and a list view. When I enter something on the search field and click find, it invokes a javascirpt function which selects the items on the list view and goes to another page/form created by the javascript function displaying the items of the list view matched with the search and a back button. when back button is clicked it was supposed to go back to first form and display the selected items on the list view. It does work properly in IE11 but it is not working in chrome. Chrome goes back to page previous to the page with search text field, find button and list view. Same happens if I click on the chorme browser back button. Chrome version is 61.

Find code below:

```
<input type="button" value="Find" onclick="fndtxt(this.form)">

function fndtxt(lgrp)
{   var txt=lgrp.srchtxt.value
    var stextgrp=txt.split(' ');
    var seltxt='You Have Selected:<br>Start Date:\n';
    var j=0,k=0;
    var selfield=''
    seltxt += lgrp.sdate.value+' and End date:'+lgrp.edate.value
    seltxt += '<br>and Following Data Fields<br>'
    for(k=0;k<document.inform.slist.length;k++){
//      document.inform.slist.options[k].selected=false;
        }
    for(k=0;k<document.inform.slist.length;k++){
    oname=document.inform.slist.options[k].text
    var sfnd=0;
    for(stxt in stextgrp){
        re = new RegExp(stextgrp[stxt],'i' )        
        if( oname.search(re)!= -1 ){
            sfnd++
            }
        }
    if(stextgrp.length==sfnd){      
        document.inform.slist.options[k].selected=true;
        seltxt=seltxt+oname+'<br>\n'
        selfield +=oname.split(':')[0]+','
        }
    }
    document.write("<html><body text='#F8B008' >");
    document.write("<head><link rel=stylesheet type='text/css' href='/wqsys/include/wqsys.css' ></head>");
    document.write("<br><br><table align=center text='#F8B008'><tr><td id=cel>");
    document.write(seltxt);
//  document.write(selfield)
    document.write("<form name='getinfo' action='nocall.pl' method=get >")
    document.write("<input type=hidden name=fname value='"+selfield+"'>")
    document.write("</td></tr><tr><td align=center><input type=button id=expmenu value='Back' onclick='history.back(-1);'>")
    document.write("</td></tr></table></form></body></html>")
    document.close()
}
```

I have tried window.history.go(-1); return false; with no success.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `history.back(-1)` works just like pressing the back button in the browser. From what you describe, it's working as you should - `document.write`ing out a new page doesn't create a history item.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz, so what would be a solution for this case?

Comment: The [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), or ditching the weird `document.write` implementation for a normal form submission.

Comment: Sorry ceejayz would you be able to show me an example to put me in the right direction?